# NullReferenceException when trying to get modified rows of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a `DataGridView`, whose `DataSource` is a `DataTable`. The user is allowed to modify the values in one specific cell in each row. I am interested in getting an `IEnumerable` of objects represented by rows that have been modified by the user.

The form implements a property as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Invoice> modifiedInvoiceRecords
{
    get
    {
        DataRowCollection modifiedRows = ((DataTable)dataGridView_invoiceHistory.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Rows;
         // iterate through the modified rows and yield return objects
    }
}
```

This yields a

> NullReferenceException

Debugging shows that the `modifiedRows` variable is always `null`. Why is this so?

Comment: Generally you want to avoid writing statements like `((DataTable)dataGridView_invoiceHistory.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Rows`.  Whilst doing so requires less code you increase the risk of runtime issues due to lack of error checking  in the code. 1) DataSource could be `null` 2) `GetChanges` **can** return `null` 3) Calling `Rows` on a possibly `null` object

Comment: You probably forgot to call `AcceptChanges()` right after the DataTable was loaded, so all Rows have the `Added` status. Call `AcceptChanges()` after you have filled the DataTable and `[DataGridView].EndEdit()` before reading the new status of those rows. Add an Elvis at the end:  `.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)?.Rows;` (if you're sure that the DataTable is not null at that point). As mentioned, you should break that *fancy line* of code into its parts.